# Set multiple variables using one SQL query that returns one row using SELECT TOP

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL query that returns the latest entry based on the id identity column but also filtered by a column. I then need to assign each column in this single row to a variable for use in a stored procedure. Below is my approach but obviously this is incorrect syntax. Thanks for the help in how to accomplish this.

```
SELECT @var1 = col1, @var2 = col2, ..., @varn = coln 
    FROM TOP 1 * FROM table WHERE col = @col ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TOP (n)` with `SELECT` statement :

```
SELECT TOP (1) @var1 = col1, @var2 = col2, ..., @varn = coln 
FROM table 
WHERE col = @col 
ORDER BY id DESC;
```